# Impersonate user between two domains

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a problem with my windows forms application. An user is identified in a machine and a domain (main domain), sometimes I need to connect to another domain(secondary domain), then I impersonate the user using logonuser api, then open files, but if I want to copy these files to the main domain the app throws a new exception **"The username or password is not correct."**

How to copy files between two domains and impersonating user with logonuser without create a memorystream?

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Do the two domains have a trust relationship set up in active directory? P.s. can you show your code please so that we know exactly how you are doing it and where the error occurs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to impersonate two users (which is essentially what "user in different domains" are) at the same time on the same thread. Either use two different threads impersonated with each variant of the user or constantly switch impersonation depending on which file you are accessing.

Note: it may be possible to open each file under corresponding user and then copy may work without switching impersonation - if that works for small sample make sure to read more before relying on it.